# My back wheel will no longer spin freely

Tags: repair

[image]im new to this site and don't know anything about how to repair bikes.
My Problem is
I put my bike into my shed (the shed is cold and damp) and never used it for 3 weeks, it was ok when I put it in but when I took it out to use it the back wheel has become very stiff, you're not able to spin it freely its just stiff. Im not sure where to start, is it the brakes or can it be something else ???

Any help would be great, the bike is less than a year old so not sure why this has happened.
Thanks

[This is my bike](http://www.bikeradar.com/mtb/gear/category/bikes/mountain-bikes/hardtail/product/review-carrera-kraken-15-49087/)

Comment: Well, are the brake pads rubbing on the rim (assuming rim brakes)? You can test this easily by releasing them and then spinning the wheel, or visually inspecting them.

Comment: Hi Batman, thanks for getting back to me so quick. My bike has disk brakes so im not sure where to go from here, do you know any common reasons for a back wheel to suddenly become stiff ? could it be anything other than the brakes ?

Comment: Is if the wheel is rubbing the frame anywhere? Does the brake disk or wheel 'wobble' when its turned. if these all appear good, remove the wheel from the bike. Hold the axle and see if it rotates cleanly. if so, spin the cassette (cogs) - they should move freely in one direction and lock in the other.  Report back here what you find.

Comment: What do you mean by "stiff"? Do you mean the wheel does not rotate freel y if you lift the bike off the ground and spin the wheel? Then please edit your question and title - "stiff" is not something most readers will understand, I think.

Comment: Hi mattnz, there is no part of the wheel rubbing against the frame anywhere, the wheel does not wobble when it turns (but the wheel hardly turns what so ever) when the wheel is off the bike the axle retains cleanly and the cogs move freely in on direction but lock when turned the other direction. Is there anyway I can adjust, or take of the disk brake to see if the brakes are the problems, also as i said i kept it in a cold damp shed, can these conditions result in a problem. Thanks mattnz

Comment: Hi sleske, yes that is correct, the wheel will not spin freely what so ever when i have it off the ground, any thoughts and ideas what the problem can be ? Thanks.

Comment: after i took the wheel off to check the things recommended, i put the wheel back on and now i can't get it to spin at all ?

Comment: Gary, is the wheel well-oriented against the frame and brake housing? Putting axle as far as possible is almoust always bad adjusting.
Is the chain well-tensioned after you mounted the wheel? Provide some photos of brake disc area.

Comment: Hi krzyski,the wheel is well-oriented and not up against the frame, im starting to think it must be the brakes, but thats just a guess. This is the first time i have had a bike with disk brakes, is there a way to disable the back brake to test if the back brake is the problem. i will included photos to see if it will help, but there not great. Thanks Krzyski

Comment: Try releasing the quick release with the bike upright on the ground, and listen for a click or clunk as the wheel settles into the dropouts, then do the QR back up. That may be why it doesn't rotate properly after you removed it. I generally do this while resting weight on the bike to hold it up, often by resting my stomach on the seat so I have both hands free. If you adjust the brake after doing that it shouldn't need adjusting aga8in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure the issue comes from your disc brake.
Check the brake pads first : there must be something wrong here because you say it was worse after you removed and put the wheel back.

I guess your brakes are hydraulic : sometimes when you store your bike in a humid place for a long time, the braking fluid will kind of "dilate", resulting in less space between the two pads, hence rubbing on the disk even if you don't press the lever.

Another test you could do is removing the caliper : if the wheel spins freely, that confirms my theory.

In that case, you need to push the pistons back to their initial position (using something to pry them apart, without damaging the pads). If you cannot, you might need to remove some fluid from the hose (there should be a small screw at the lever), but be careful not let some air go in the hose.

Comment: Thanks for that, i can't push the pistons back, so how much fluid do you think i should remove ? and again thanks :0)

Comment: Start with something like five drops, close the screw, and try to push the pistons again. Beware, the fluid is quite corrosive and can damage the paint on your lever/bar, so use a tissue to put on the hole where you removed the screw (that also prevents air from going in).

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the disc brake. It might be that the hub is seized up from rust. You can check if it is the brake or not by loosening the caliper and spinning the wheel. If it spins freely it is the brake not the hub.

If it is the hub you might need to get it regreased. Alternatively it might just be overtightened (although its not likely to tighten by itself in the shed).

If it is the disc, check the alignment of the caliper and that the pistons inside are not pushed in too far, e.g. from putting on the brake where there is no disc in the caliper. you can take out the pads, prize apart the piston, put the pads bad in then pump the lever (with the wheel and rotor in place obvs).

Comment: I think it is pretty unlikely that rust in the hub will lock the wheel in such a short period. But, of course, greasing, if there is no "machine bearing" is always a good idea.

Comment: 3 years in a cold and damp shed. It depends how cold and how damp :)

Comment: He said: 3 weeks ...

Comment: haha yes my bad. Some cheap disc rotors rust up quick.